# I am clicking a button and to that button i want to add class

Tags: javascript

i want to add class to the button that i got clicked. i am trying toget id of button and then adding class to it but it doesnot seem working. Any help would be appericiated

```
$('.btn').click(function(event){
    let buttonClicked = this.id
    console.log(buttonClicked)
    buttonClicked.classList.add('random')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle both adding **random** to the element and removing it after the timeout set.

```
        $(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
            var buttonClicked = this;
            buttonClicked.classList.add('random');
            setTimeout(function () {
                buttonClicked.classList.remove('random')
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('random');
    callRemove();
});

function callRemove(){
    setTimeout(function(
        $('.btn').removeClass('random');
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Why should OP thry this. expplain what you have changed and why